# Sonarqube project analyse takes more and more time

Tags: jenkins, java-8, sonarqube, maven-3, sonarqube-scan

Using Jenkins 1.642.2 for code analysis with SonarQube 5.6.1 for all my maven projects.

i use : sonar-java-plugin-4.2.jar

i tried Sonarqube scan & sonarqube runner i have the same problem when i start my build in Jenkins with :

```
$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN
```

it takes a long time with sonarqube 5.6.1 but it's work very well with sonarqube 4.5.1

```
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=48ms
INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor
INFO: Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): none
INFO: JavaClasspath initialization
WARN: Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of source files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.libraries property
INFO: JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=0ms
INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization
WARN: Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of test files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.test.libraries property
INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Java Main Files AST scan
INFO: 140 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 66/140 files analyzed, current file: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/INT_FR_Quality-test/workspace/MEjb/accDocMgr/src/main/java/com/jd/boas/process/billing/accdocmgr/impl/AccDocMgrMapper.java
INFO: Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=15608ms
INFO: Java Test Files AST scan
INFO: 140/140 source files have been analyzed
INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=16072ms
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
INFO: SCM provider for this project is: svn
INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
INFO: 140 files to be analyzed
INFO: 1/140 files analyzed
INFO: 4/140 files analyzed
INFO: 7/140 files analyzed
INFO: 9/140 files analyzed
INFO: 12/140 files analyzed
.
.
.
INFO: 136/140 files analyzed
INFO: 138/140 files analyzed
INFO: 140/140 files analyzed
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=1065164ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=114ms
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=5ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: JavaCpdBlockIndexer is used for java
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=305ms
```

the project scan need more than 10 hours !!!
any help please

Comment: Except maybe for the SCM sensor which takes about 17min to be run, there is absolutely nothing helpful or indicating a 10 hours analysis for the project  in the log you provided. Would you be able to share more information ? more relevant log maybe ? try to pinpoint where time is spent ?

Comment: My project has a lot of modules so i test one module but i see the time is spent in the SCM sensor but when i add -Dsonar.scm.disabled=true i  have 0 file analysed in sonarqube
i tried with the svn plugin 1.2 and 1.3 with the same probleme
the log http://pastebin.com/0q1hNJWf:

Answer (score 0):

try on a fresh database with no previous data. Is analyse still long ? If not it means that your current database had to be re-index and so on